# Spring @Inject service class return null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I have a `Converter` class where I have used the following so that I can use `@Inject` to access my service class.

```
@Named("myMB")
@ViewAccessScoped
```

However when I tried to use

```
myservice.getCategories();
```

I am getting `null pointer exception` at this line. What could be the reason for this?
I have used the same service method in `ManagedBean` to populate `selectOneMenu`, but when
used in Converter class, gives me exception.

**Converter class**

```
@FacesConverter("categoryConverter")
@Named("myMB")
@ViewAccessScoped
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter {

@Inject
CategoryService myservice;

    @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component,
                String value) {
            System.out.println("reached in converter "+value);
            try {


                    List<Category> cat = myservice.getCategories();
                    for (Category cat : category) {
                        if (cat.getCategoryCode() == value) {
                            return cat;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("exception from getAsObject  ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can happen if you used it as `@FacesConverter` instance instead of as `@Named` instance. The `@Inject` doesn't work on `@FacesConverter`. Get rid of `@FacesConverter` to avoid future confusion and reference the converter as `converter="#{categoryConverter}"` (which uses `@Named`) instead of as `converter="categoryConverter"` (which uses `@FacesConverter`).

Note that I assume that the Spring part is properly configured, otherwise it would be still `null`. I don't do Spring, so I can't tell form top of head if it works inside a CDI managed bean instead of a Spring managed bean. I find it only surprising and amusing that you're mixing CDI and Spring, while Spring is intented as competitor/alternative to CDI/EJB.

Comment: BalusC is absolutely right. What actually happens behind the scenes is that JSF context itself will instantiate classes annotated with @FacesConverter. Since this happens outside Spring context no dependencies will get injected.